# Use data from factory in controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controller

I am very new to AngularJS.
I want to pass an array data from my app factory to app controller.

Here is my app.factory code.

```
App.factory('buyFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
        factory.Search = function(scope, d) {
          var data = scope.search;
          scope.CarsData = [];
          all_cars = [];
          scope.isLoading = true;
          $http.post(ajaxurl + '?action=search_car', d)
            .success(function(response) {
                angular.forEach(response, function(c) {
                  c.price = parseFloat(c.price);
                  c.driven = parseFloat(c.driven);
                  c.year = parseFloat(c.year);
                });

                angular.forEach(response, function(value, key) {
                    all_cars.push(value);
                    scope.CarsData = all_cars;
                    scope.TotalItems = scope.CarsData.length;
                    scope.isLoading = false;
                  })
                  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                    scope.isLoading = false;

                  });
              }
              return factory;
            }]);
```

and this is app.controller as

```
App.controller('buyController', ['$scope', '$http', 'buyFactory', '$filter', function($scope, $http, buyFactory, $filter) {
  $scope.CarsScroll = buyFactory.Search.CarsData();
  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    var last = $scope.CarsScroll[$scope.CarsScroll.length - 1];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      $scope.CarsScroll.push(last + i);
    }
  };
  //scroll


}]);
```

I want to use output obtained from factory i.e. `CarsData` as a variable in my app controller. But I am not able to get it. I have tried using services also. Is there method to use array data in a simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is completely broken, i would recommend following any course of AngularJS. As for how to correctly do what you are trying to would look something like this

```
app.factory('buyFactory', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) { 
    var factory = {
        search: function(d) {           
            return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                $http.post(ajaxurl + '?action=search_car', d).then(function(response) {
                    angular.forEach(response, function(c) {
                        c.price = parseFloat(c.price);
                        c.driven = parseFloat(c.driven);
                        c.year = parseFloat(c.year);
                    });
                    var carsData = [];
                    angular.forEach(response, function(value, key) {                        
                        carsData.push(value);
                    })

                    var result = {
                        carsData: carsData,
                        total: carsData.length
                    }                   
                    resolve(result);                    
                }, function(error) {                    
                    reject(error);
                })              
            });         
        }
    }

    return factory;
}]);

app.controller('buyController', ['$scope', '$http', 'buyFactory', '$filter', function($scope, $http, buyFactory, $filter) {
  buyFactory.search().then(function(result) {
      var cars = result.carsData;
      var total = result.total;
  })
}]);
```

Note: i do not know what the d parameter is for neither why the angular.forEach statements so it might not be fully functional. But this is more as guideline for how your factory should look and be used.

Comment: I had removed some lines of comment which is not relevant here. I am getting value of 'CarsData' is the form of array  [{}, {}, {}, {}]). I want to used same array in my controller.